# Segment Selector in IA-32

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86

When does segment selector comes in picture. The line in Intel Guide says:

> "Each segment descriptor has an associated segment selector. A segment
>   selector provides the software that uses it with an index into the GDT
>   or LDT (the offset of its associated segment descriptor), a
>   global/local flag (determines whether the selector points to the GDT
>   or the LDT), and access rights information."

I didn't quite get it.

Are there separate segment selector register(s)? 
   How is it calculated?
   Why we need it.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So what happens is:

Whenever a program is loaded, the linking loader loads the "Segment Registers" with the appropriate selectors. 
A Segment Register ( e.g. CS, DS, SS, etc) is divided in two parts: Visible and Hidden. 
It is the visible part which is loaded by the loader with the appropriate value. 
This value is an index in GDT or LDT, depending on the TI flag of the selector.
The processor loads the hidden part by itself. The information in hidden part is the segment base address in the linear address space, segment limit, access information.

Answer (score 27):

GDT stands for *Global Descriptor Table*.
The important thing here is the word **table** and by table Intel means array.

Being <strike>a table</strike> an array it has elements, each element is called **Descriptor**. Of course each element can be indexed, i.e. it has an unique index

The *segment selector* registers hold the index of a descriptor. The value into a segment selector register is called *selector*.

However things are a bit more elaborated.
An *index* **is not** a *selector*.

Beside the *index*, a segment selector register, holds two more things:

1. The privilege that the programmer want to use for accessing the *descriptor*. This is called **RPL** (Request Privilege Level) for every register but `CS` in which is called **CPL** (Current Privilege Level). The role *RPL* and *CPL* play in using the segment selector register is defined in Intel manuals and it is too long to be explained here.
2. The table to use for looking into. One table is the *GDT* the other one is the *LDT*. Again differences and uses are in the Intel manuals.

So the informal rule is:

**selector** = *index* + *table_to_use* + *privilege*
**table_to_use + index** = *descriptor* = *all the information about the segment of memory to be used*

where, of course, `+` does not mean arithmetic plus at all. The actual bit field for a segment selector register is

```
15                                                 3    2        0
+--------------------------------------------------+----+--------+
|          Index                                   | TI |   RPL  |
+--------------------------------------------------+----+--------+

TI = Table Indicator: 0 = GDT, 1 = LDT
```

So for example the value `05h` select the descriptor with index 0 (in the *LDT* using *RPL*=1), which is invalid as Intel explicitly mandates to not use the descriptor 0.
The first usable *descriptor* is accessible with the *selector* `08h` which select as table the *GDT* with *RPL*=0. The values `08h-0bh` all select the *descriptor* with index 1 in the *GDT*, just with different *RPL*.

Here's a complete ASCII art of the terminology

```
<---- Selector ---->    +----- Segment Selector Register
+-------+----+-----+    v
| Index | TI | RPL | = DS
+-------+----+-----+            GDT                        LDT
   |      |             +---------------------+   +---------------------+
   |      +------------>| Null Descriptor     |   | Null Descriptor     |
   |                    +---------------------+   +---------------------+
   |                    | Descriptor 1        |   | Descriptor 1        |
   |                    +---------------------+   +---------------------+
   |                    |                     |   |                     |
   |                    ...     ...    ...   ...  ...     ...    ...   ...
   |                    |                     |
   |                    +---------------------+
   +------------------->| Descriptor K        |
                        +---------------------+
                        |                     |
                        ...     ...    ...   ...
```

**About how it is calculated and why we need it**

*Short answer*: Read the Intel manual as it is the complete reference.

*Long answer*: We, user mode programmers, don't calculate it. Since all this thing with the segments boils down to limiting the privileges of a program and since it is the OS that commands and not us, we simply use the value that the OS gives us (by loading our program basically) as the *GDT* and the  *LDT* are set up by the OS and it is now willing to cooperate with us in any aspect of it.

We need segments because in *Real mode* there were segments (Google for more info), because they can avoid relocation an gather isolation in absence of paging (Google for more info) and because segments now incorporates more info than a simply base offset and a limit. One of all: the **Descriptor Privilege Level** that limits the privileges of a user mode program.

Comment: LDTs unlike the GDT don't have a NULL descriptor entry so the first entry is valid

Comment: where did you find "The segment selector registers " which processor's architecture you see segment selector being a register?

Comment: @RaGa__M on 80286+ all the segment registers in real mode become selectors in protected mode and compatibility mode. I believe when they say segment selector registers they refer to CS, DS, ES, FS, GS, and SS.

Answer (score 1):

In real mode, access to the memory is segmented, i.e. it is accessed by specifying the segment location and the segment offset. The physical address is then calculated by adding the offset to the shifted-left segment location. Both the segment location segment and the segment offset were 16 bits.

Because of Intel's design choices, which were apparently very highly focused on backwards compatibility, they chose to keep the 16-bit size of the segment registers. That caused problems when protected mode came into the picture. In protected mode, a GDT (Global Descriptor Table) and a LDT (Local Descriptor Table) are kept somewhere in memory. These descriptors have all the necessary data about the segments that the processor works with. In order to access these descriptors, you need a segment selector, which is essentially an index into the array of segment descriptors (i.e. the LDT or GDT).

Essentially, specifying 5 as the value of the segment selector causes the CPU to use the 5th (indexing starts at zero) descriptor in the Local/Global Descriptor Table.

Comment: Then, how to obtain the segment selector?

Comment: You can't obtain it, it's a value you set based on which of the segment descriptors you want to use in the application.

Comment: So we need to know the segment selector to select the segment descriptor. Now when a context switch occurs from where is the selector taken?

Comment: You use `LGDT/LLDT/LIDT` instructions to load descriptor tables. Then any value you assign to a selector becomes an index into descriptor table. For instance assigning 3 to ES means value of 3rd entry in descriptor table you loaded before. and any access using ES: prefix will cause memory to be accessed using that entry's contents.